# Date issue in Server IIS with codeigniter..

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, iis

I have a strange date issue . I am using codeigniter framework , date is working properly in my localhost . but once I uploaded to server it showing some database error --------- I am using IIS server

```
Error Number: 1292 

Incorrect datetime value: '2014-07-03T09:33:17Z' for column 'login_time' at row 1 

INSERT INTO `login_table` (`userid`, `user_name`, `status`, `login_time`) VALUES ('25', 'M0383799X', 'Success', '2014-07-03T09:33:17Z')
```

can any one can help me on this ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change `2014-07-03T09:33:17Z` to `2014-07-03 9:33:17` like this

```
INSERT INTO `login_table` 
(`userid`, `user_name`, `status`, `login_time`) VALUES 
('25', 'M0383799X', 'Success', '2014-07-03 9:33:17')
```

Comment: can you explain me ..why it working like that ....it working properly in localhost when I uploaded to server it is giving issue ??? ....thank you